# Spring data JPA left join on two unrelated tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have following two entities where there is no relationship b/w them.I would like to perform left join get data from both the tables.As spring repository provides return result on only one table how can i modify my code to get data from both the tables.

```
@Table(value = "customer")
data class Customer(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val groupNumber: String,
)

@Table(value = "customer_policy")
data class Customer_Policy(
    val audt_id: Int,
    val policyNUmber: String,
    val groupNumber: String,
)
```

Here is my query

```
Select c.name,cp.policuNumber from Customer c left join customer_policy on c.groupNumber = cp.groupNumber
```

How Can i define an interface repository which returns the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Data JPA you have the annotation `@Query` where you can add your query straight in the interface methods.

Your repository interface would look something like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository interface CustomerRepo: JpaRepository<CustomResponseEntity, Long> {

  @Query("Select c.name,cp.policuNumber from Customer c left join customer_policy cp on c.groupNumber = cp.groupNumber")
  fun findSomething():
    List<CustomResponseEntity>
}
```

Here you have a deeper explanation:
[Query annotation and examples](https://blog.trifork.com/2018/08/28/spring-data-native-queries-and-projections-in-kotlin/)

Comment: so the Result object is plain old pojo with two result columns?And what interface return type is 
interface ReactiveCrudRepository<Result, String>
{
    @Query("Select c.name,cp.policuNumber from Customer c left join customer_policy cp on c.groupNumber = cp.groupNumber")
    fun findSomething(): Collection<Result>?
}

Comment: I updated my answer and put a better link with explanations that i found.

Comment: You can also define your custom entity response (a projection) with two parameters.